# Is there a good way to download scipy, numpy, matplotlib, and pandas documentation for pylookup?

Tags: python, emacs, download

Pylookup is a project in emacs to view python documentation in a browser, rather than in the interpreter: http://taesoo.org/proj/pylookup.html

Essentially, it requires documentation in this format:

1. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/genindex.html
2. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/genindex.html
3. http://matplotlib.org/genindex.html
4. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/genindex.html

How can I download these help directories so I can access them locally?

Answer (score 11):

Go to http://docs.scipy.org/doc/ and download the Numpy and Scipy reference guides in the format "HTML+zip", unzip them to `$DOCDIRECTORY` and call `./pylookup.py -a -u "$DOCDIRECTORY"`. It should pick up the `genindex.html` from the directory.

For Matplotlib you might have to download the whole source (or the relevant part from https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/doc) and build the HTML documentation yourself.

For Pandas try http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/pandas.zip, it also provides a `genindex.html`.

Comment: Good answer. So what about `pandas`?

Comment: @FrozenFlame: I added a link. For most packages you can find the reference documentation in this format on their web sites.

Answer (score 0):

For matplotlib they appear to add each version to this repository: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib.github.com